# Is there a program for theory of incompleteness in $NP$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Motivated by Suresh's post, [Techniques for showing that problem is in hardness limbo](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/techniques-for-showing-that-problem-is-in-hardness-limbo/20891), it seems that there might be an underlying theory that explains why some of these problems can **not** be complete for $NP$.

For instance, the theory should explain why problems with polynomially bounded solutions (FewP) can not be complete. Also, it should explain why problems solvable by bounded nondeterminism (log-clique) can not be complete.

> Is there a research program that tries to link the apparent incompleteness of at least two candidate problems in Suresh's post? What are the obstacles to such program?

**EDIT**: I am also interested in published research studying the connection between incomplete sets for $NP$ and finite versions of Godel's 2nd incompleteness theorem in the context of proof complexity.
Posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206807/is-there-a-program-for-theory-of-incompleteness-in-np).

**EDIT 2**:

Some of the results in Suresh's post can be interpreted as (conjectured) necessary conditions for the NP-completeness of a given problem B:

1- Problem B must be exponentially dense.

2- Problem B can have exponential number of solutions.

3- Problem B must require linear nondeterministic bits to solve.

Comment: Wasn't there a question about "NPI-complete"?

Comment: @kaveh Here we want the connection between two completely different NPI problems.

Comment: agreed with K, this is basically the study of the [NPI](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?q=npi+is%3Aquestion) "class"

Comment: NP-Incomplete = NPI union P

Comment: @TysonWilliams Yes, that is correct.