# Techniques for showing intermediate status between $\mathsf{NP \cap coNP}$ and coNP-completeness

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, proof-complexity

Inspired by [Suresh's post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/techniques-for-showing-that-problem-is-in-hardness-limbo), for a new problem in $\mathsf{coNP}$, whose true proof complexity is intermediate between $\mathsf{NP \cap coNP}$ and being coNP-complete, I am interested in methods which show that it is probably hard to prove the existence of good characterization.

> What techniques and methods do exist to show that a $coNP$ problem might not have good characterization?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, graph isomorphism is not even known to be in co[Q](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qma)M[A](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#maexp)<sub>S[UBEXP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#subexp)</sub>, so it would presumably be difficult to show that there is a GI-complete problem in coNP. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Edited the post according to your comment.

Comment: On the other hand, one "such method is to show that the problem is" coGI-complete. $\hspace{1.35 in}$